# Cygwin cross-compilation for Raspbian failed due to "'__PTHREAD SPINS' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: cygwin, cross-compiling, raspbian

I want to compile a project from me for raspbian. Previously I could compile it without any problems. Then I updated raspbian to the newest version (sketch) and my Cygwin did not like that.

The error I get is the following:

```
    C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe -c -Wall --ansi -std=c++11 -DVERSION='"0.9.0.manual_20180327_150647.30458ef1"' -DUSE_RASPICAM -DUSE_I2C -IC:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include -IC:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/local/include -o objects/projectfile.o projectfile.cpp
    In file included from c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\bits\gthr-default.h:35:0,
             from c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\bits\gthr.h:148,
             from c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\ext\atomicity.h:35,
             from c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\memory:73,
             from projectfile.cpp:7:
    c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\ext\concurrence.h:122:34: error: '__PTHREAD_SPINS' was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_t _M_mutex = __GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;
                              ^
    c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\ext\concurrence.h:177:44: error: '__PTHREAD_SPINS' was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_t _M_mutex = __GTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INIT;
                                        ^
    c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\mutex:63:31: error: '__PTHREAD_SPINS' was not declared in this scope
 __native_type  _M_mutex = __GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;
                           ^
    c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\mutex:92:31: error: '__PTHREAD_SPINS' was not declared in this scope
 __native_type  _M_mutex = __GTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INIT;
```

Previousy I could compile without problems. So I syncronized the sysroot again which is at C:\sysgcc\raspberry\sysroot\ .
Also I updated all installed packages for my cygwin.

When I google the failure I only find that libc6 could be broken - I reinstalled the newest version which should fix the problem, but it did not fix it.

Can anybody tell me what I could try next to be able to compile?

projectfile.cpp line 7 is:

```
    #include <memory>
```

When I am compiling the project on a pi there is no problem so the sysroot seems to be ok.

Comment: I do not see the cygwin relevance as the cross compiler seems a windows program.

Comment: I do not now much about that stuff with cross compiling. I was happy when it was working. Now it don't and I don't have any idea how to fix it.